# How do I view the Edit History?

Tags: support

I recently saw a link in a comment for the "Edit History" of a question.  How do I view that history without someone posting a link to it in the Comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get to the edit history by clicking on this link:

[image: edit history link circled in red]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a link to it directly above the profile pic of the last person who edited the question (or just a bit further over from the OP's profile pic (and slightly above) if they are the only one who has edited it).

*edit1: I hereby include both'a thousand words' & '1001 words' blah, blah, blah,... (imagine this succession of 'blah's repeated another 900 times or so - I'll spare myself and further on-lookers the trouble of actually producing/viewing it in reality)  - to pander to the jokers hijacking my answer!*

*edit2: but now that i've done that I can say - just look down here for the edit history:*
............................................................................**|**..................................................................................................................................................................**V**

Comment: Wow. Only 12 seconds apart. :P

Comment: @El'endiaStarman my hat is definitely off to you sir - a picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: So put 1001 words in your answer! :P ;)

Comment: Yes, but **which** thousand words? ;-P

Comment: @MattGutting: HA! Yes indeed...

Comment: Screen shot anybody?